# Excel macro pauses using a timer, I want to use a button to restart it

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, charts

How can I restart my macro using a click event, replacing my current timer method?

I have to manually update chart labels before I create a PDF to print. I've included a  timer to pause the macro allowing me a certain amount of time to make my changes before it pops up a message box and I'm obliged to begin the next part of my macro.

It's rather hit and miss: some chart labels require more manipulation.

...and surprisingly stressful.

```
sub PauseMacro
MsgBox "15s to change the labels positions of the pie charts"
t1 = Now
While Now < t1 + TimeSerial(0, 0, 15)
    DoEvents
Wend
MsgBox "Continuing with updating countries macro"
End Sub
```

(This useful piece of code came form an answer on this forum. Apologies I can't find the original thread).

The ideal would be a message box button that waits for me (or other users who will inherit this task) to click "Continue" once we have made our changes to the labels.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to figure out how to interact with the Excel chart while a form is open.

Any pointers very welcome.
Michael.

Comment: *Use the form* http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom/vba-script-to-pause-macro-allow-editing-then/53027408-ed41-4300-b42e-ed2fc20b8e9c?auth=1

Comment: Is the problem that you can't control the sheet while the form is open? Because that's a solvable problem. If you could control the sheet with the msgbox open, it would be a good solution?

Comment: @BigElittles I think that's the issue. I built a simple pause because when the msg box was visible I couldn't interact with the Excel sheet itself.

Comment: As far as I know, MsgBox pauses the code. I assume that if you let the Message stay on the screen for 15 seconds, the timer will still be at 15 seconds?

Comment: A couple screen shots would be nice to see. I don't understand. Are you timing yourself to see how fast you can do a task? Is this a timed test? I don't understand what the timer's intended purpose is. What do you mean by, "...while a form is open"? You are working with Charts and Forms? I don't see that anywhere in your example except for your last mention in the last statement. This piece of code opens a message and will halt anything until you press ok. The after you finally press OK, it waits 15 seconds until it appears again. What is your goal? Task? Work?

Comment: @ejbytes. I am automating the process for producing country information sheets. These contain charts. For some of these countries the data labels have to be moved manually to stop them overlapping. I'm trying to pause my macro so I can move the data labels and then restart it. Currently it pauses it for a fixed amount (slightly stressful), I'm wondering if it can be paused until I click a button and it restarts the macro.

Comment: Restart means start from the beginning. If all you want to do is restart it, the only thing you would have to do is restart it. The pause is unnecessary as you've described it. Trivial at best.A button could be used or shortcut key.

Answer (score 0):

Found [Here on StackOverflow, by Siddharth Rout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603626/how-to-still-keep-working-in-excel-while-msgbox-is-on)
Read the link first, then come back here for more specific details.

My Tips: Make the form very simple and basic, make it look like the familiar msgbox everyone is used to. The one thing that you will have to include is a continue button on the form.

You will still need some kind of loop, because loading a form will not actually stop the code from running. I would use the forms onload event to code for the timer/loop.

Also, I don't know your process... but another thing I just thought of...You could avoid all of the form stuff if you wanted to create a worksheet and name it "Continue" And whenever all the manual edits are made, just click the sheet named continue and it would boot it out of the loop thats running, waiting for the sheet named "Continue" to be active. Once it's active delete the sheet and resume the code.   This is probably the quickest way of doing what you want, its ugly... but most workarounds are lol.

Comment: Thanks. I'll read the link you sent me. I'm new to VBA so a lot of my working practices are simply try-it-and-see type processes.